# UITextView.textDidChangeNotification not working in iOS 16 and Xcode 14.2?

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, wkwebview

I'm currently working on an iOS app using Xcode 14.2 and targeting iOS 16. I have a WKWebView that I want to monitor for text changes using the textDidChangeNotification notification. However, it seems that the notification is not being triggered when the text changes in the WKWebView. I have confirmed that the WKWebView is editable and is set up as a responder object. I have also verified that the textDidChangeNotification notification is registered correctly using NotificationCenter.default.addObserver.

This code was working fine in previous versions of iOS and Xcode, so I'm wondering if there have been any changes that might have caused this issue. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Is there a workaround or a different approach I can take to monitor text changes in a WKWebView in iOS 16?

my codes:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textDidChanged), name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

my xcode version: Version 14.2 (14C18)
my iOS version: iOS16.3.1(20D67)  newest now